# Spring Security Oauth2 logout using @FrameworkEndpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, logout, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to logout by revoking `access_token` like this :

```
@FrameworkEndpoint
public class SecurityLogoutController {
  @Autowired
  private ConsumerTokenServices                 consumerTokenServices;

  @DeleteMapping( "/oauth/token" )
  public ResponseEntity<Void> logout( WebRequest request ) {
    String bearer = "bearer";
    String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader( HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION );
    log.info( "authorization header: {}", authorizationHeader );
    if ( authorizationHeader != null && StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase( authorizationHeader, bearer ) ) {
        String accessTokenID = authorizationHeader.substring( bearer.length() + 1 );
        log.info( "access_token: {}", accessTokenID );
        consumerTokenServices.revokeToken( accessTokenID );
    }
    return ...;
  }
}
```

But every time I send this delete request with Postman I got this response:

```
{
 "timestamp": "2018-05-30T01:09:11.710+0000",
 "status": 401,
 "error": "Unauthorized",
 "message": "Unauthorized",
 "path": "/oauth/token"
}
```

The endpoint is protected by Spring Security behind the scene and I don't know how and where this endpoint is protected. What I don't understand is: why the client should authenticate again since to get the `access_token` it had been authenticated? It seems strange for me.

Now when I authenticate the client, Postman automatically replace the `Authorization` header value and set it with basic authentication. Something like: `Basic Y2hpY293YS11aXNlcnZpY2U6Y2aXNlcnZpY2U=`

Need some helps... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually makes sense because a logout can be done with the provided token by the one who already is logged in. The browser app will for sure have the client_id and secret to pass.

Even I have same problem and have posted the same on SO. Well.. one way out is that you do basic authentication with client_id and secret and importantly pass another header called AUTH-TOKEN (or something else) with the value of the actual token that you want to delete. Here is the code

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/oauth/token")
@ResponseBody
public void revokeToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String authorization = request.getHeader("AUTH-TOKEN");
    if (authorization != null && authorization.contains("Bearer")) {
                String tokenId = authorization.substring("Bearer".length() + 1);
                System.out.println("tokenId : " + tokenId);
                tokenServices.revokeToken(tokenId);
                //tokenStore.removeRefreshToken(token);   
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. So, is it just a test issue with Postman? I mean if I use a browser (or mobile) client app with its credential (client_id + secret), the code will work?

Comment: This is an issue with NOT just postman I believe; though I did not test the same through the app.