# Logout doesn't work with Spring Boot, Spring Security and Thymleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I’m trying to add a logout function for our Spring Boot application but Spring logout does not work... The authenticated user still exists and it doesn’t clear the security context. What actually surprises me, it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn’t. I have no idea why!

Thymeleaf:

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript: document.logoutForm.submit()" role="menuitem"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout</a></li>
           <form name="logoutForm" th:action="@{/logout}" method="post" th:hidden="true">
                        <input hidden type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
            </form>
```

Here is my code block for logout;

```
.logout()
.clearAuthentication(true)
.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
.logoutSuccessUrl("/oauth2/authorization/login")
.addLogoutHandler(new HeaderWriterLogoutHandler(
      new ClearSiteDataHeaderWriter(
            ClearSiteDataHeaderWriter.Directive.CACHE,
            ClearSiteDataHeaderWriter.Directive.COOKIES,
            ClearSiteDataHeaderWriter.Directive.STORAGE)));
```

I also tried but it didn’t help;

```
.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
.invalidateHttpSession(true)
```

Does anyone have any idea why it has such strange behavior?

Comment: You logoutSuccessUrl suggests that you're using OAuth2, logout in OAuth2 is a very specific flow. If you're using it, you might want to check if you're really logging out of the Authorization Server.

Comment: I have the same opinion as @Raphael. If OAuth is involved, it is very likely that you need to logout from your OAuth server. Please, can you provide further information about how OAuth is configured in your application? You provided a relative URL as logout url, maybe you are implementing it in the own app? If you are using Spring for the task, please, consider read the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595226/spring-security-oauth2-logout-using-frameworkendpoint) SO question, using the `Authorization` header instead of `AUTH-TOKEN`. See next comment

Comment: This functionally should be implemented in a logout endpoint; this endpoint will then redirect to your actual logout URL. I mean, for example: `.logoutSuccessUrl("/oauth2/authorization/logout?redirect_uri=/oauth2/authorization/login")`. I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume the problem is incomplete configuration for oauth2 login/logout configuration:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
    
    private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() { 
        ...
    }
}
```

Pay attention to two moments:

- `.oauth2Login()` - configures authentication support using an OAuth 2.0
- `.logoutSuccessHandler(...)` - redirects on proper oauth2 server logout endpoint for user ending session.
  Unfortunate I don't know your oauth2 provider, anyway I recommend look at `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` to figure out how to redirect to the logout url. if you don't use `openid` oauth2 provider you can implement you own logout handler based on `SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler`, you should know only logout url and url parameter for redirecting after success logout on oauth2 server.

Comment: I also tried this one and it didn't help either :/

Comment: @merdle Could you please add code how did you implement ```logoutHandler``` and which oauth provider did you use?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Now it is resolved. I used below code:

```java
.and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutSuccess").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true);
```

Try this one. It is working on my machine.

Comment: Thanks krishnkant but I also tried this one and it didn't help either :/